# Sharepoint access files (.pdf, .xlsx) with private access

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am using microsoft sharepoint to store all files (.pdf and .xlsx) when the site was public I was able to list all files in a particular folder and access each file inside it.
using the below url

https://{site-url}/_api/lists/getbytitle({title})/items

But since the site is private, I can get the response of the same API using an access token. But when I am opening the files if I am logged in chrome and my user has access to the site I am able to see the file. But in incognito I am unable to see the file, it asks me to login.

how can I make the private file visible using access token?

I have read the documentation but it does not resolve my problem.